# In html how do you have an image overlapping an other image?

Tags: html, css

How do you get an image to overlap another image , I can get text to overlap my background image but i wanted a series of images on top of that image.

Comment: Use z-index in CSS

Comment: poor arguments. try making a effort to produce a more argumented question, nobody willl guess what you want,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `z-index`, the higher the number, the higher it stacks in the pile (ie - closer to the viewer):

```css
img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.image1 {
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.image2 {
  z-index: 999;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.image3 {
  z-index: 99;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.image4 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<img class="image1" src="http://gallery.photo.net/photo/6182716-md.jpg">
<img class="image2" src="http://gallery.photo.net/photo/12682192-md.jpg">
<img class="image3" src="http://gallery.photo.net/photo/2568318-md.jpg">
<img class="image4" src="http://gallery.photo.net/photo/6506352-lg.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you only want an image above your background image, then just place your image in what ever content you have.
If you want images over images, use z-index

Apply a z-index to each of your images, with the highest number being the "highest" image.

```
Z-index: 1;
Z-index: 2;
Z-index: 3;
```

Etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Higher the value of z-index comes in front.